# SharePoint 2007 - Option to edit existing documents but not add

Tags: sharepoint

I have a client who still uses SP 2007. They have a requirement to allow users to edit existing documents but not add new documents to a library.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a new custom permission level and assign it to a group or people who need this level of access to the library

[Creating a custom permission level](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mediumbusiness/archive/2011/09/23/create-custom-permissions-for-sharepoint.aspx)

Replicate the current permission level but do not tick the Add item to the custom permission.

Warning : Do not update the out of the box permission level

Cheers

Truez